# Replace PE in embedded icon image, without re-signing the file all over again

Tags: windows, digital-signature, code-signing, portable-executable

Is there any option to set new icon for a signed PE executable in windows without re-signing it all over again?

This means that the icon image, although fully embedded into the PE file, won't change the hash value as it's appears in the file signature part.

perhaps there's a concept where one can sign only the code and data section of the file and avoid other parts ? or maybe there's an option to exclude unwanted parts from the signature cover ?

Maybe it's possible to place the icon somehow inside the certificate section itself which is created by SignTool, so that it would be excluded from signing?

thanks

Comment: @RbMm, perhaps do you know how it can be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the signTool provided by microsoft that is used to sign binary files is not able to partially sign files. And it wouldn't make much sense to sign a binary if anyone could just change the embedded resources - the application code might rely on the data in those resources. So if the resource's integrity is not covered by the signature, the executable code would also be untrusted, thus defeating the purpose of the signature.

A solution would be to externalize the resources, so it's not part of the signature. It just might be possible by specifying an external path to the icon in the application's manifest file - but I'm not sure.

Comment: That's can be an option, but I hope to find a way even when the icon is embedded inside the file, by somehow skip this section when calculating file hash (like it skip the certificate hash)

Comment: I think about the only place you could store additional data without resigning the file would be the certificate itself. There's probably some extra-data fields that you could manipulate, but there is no way to make windows explorer interpret part of the certificate as the file-icon. Simply put: there is no place (inside the exe) to store your icon that is not part of the input to the SHA-checksum, that windows explorer will search for icons.

Comment: @markus-nm, Hi.. perhaps you can elaborate some more about how to externalize the resources from PE using manifest  ?